# shorter syntax to bind multiple click events - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Is there a shorter syntax to write this

```
$('.class1').click(function() {
   some_function1();
});

$('.class2').click(function() {
   some_function2();
});

$('.class3').click(function() {
   some_function3();
});

$('.class4').click(function() {
   some_function4();
});
```

knowing all the functions are different !

Comment: Not really, you could use same handler for all elements but then need to filter which callback to call depending of which element clicked

Comment: @A.Wolff could you say how to use the same handler for all elements ?

Comment: I think a more effective way would be to have a class you put on all of these and assign them the right function based on the class. But if you need this kind of separation then you can't really* make it more efficient.

* I say really as in you could... but it wouldn't be noticeable to the human eye, it would make ten's of ms different.

Comment: `$('.class1,.class2,...).click(...)` this is what i mean, not really short cut as you still need to filter inside handler which element has been clicked

Comment: Ah yes Ok, I knew about that, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a proof of concept. Of course, you'd need to validate the regex return etc.. but its something to think about: Assuming the class will end in a number, and you have the corresponding function etc..

```
$('.class1, .class2').click(function() {
  var num = 'some_function' + this.className.match(/(\d+)$/)[0];
  test[num]();
});

var test = {
   some_function1:function(){
      console.log('in func 1 ');
   },
   some_function2:function(){
      console.log('in func 2 ');
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Since the functions does not seems to be accepting any special parameters, pass them as the callback itself

```
$('.class1').click(some_function1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//param1: class name as string param2: function to execute
function binder(class, f){
  $("'."+class+"'").click(f);
}
```

then call the function with your classes.

Comment: Arun's answer is still better in this case or i don't see how you can use that